# Duplicate range slider

Tags: javascript

I want to make a form a bit similar to the one below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgZ9j.gif

The point is to duplicate the range slider in order to choose a letter, and then the letter is added up automatically into the main input field. Each new letter selection with a new slider adds an extra letter in the input field.

I've tried `clone()` but of course every new slider gets the value of the first one, so it doesn't help. Now I've defined my slider into a function, and calls the function every time the button is clicked. But the new slider replaces the value of the former one in the main input field.There's no HTML other than a div with the id "target". Here's my Javascript code:

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');

// Instruction
var instruction = document.createElement('p');
    instruction.innerHTML = 'Enter your first name:';
    target.appendChild(instruction);

// Input for name
var letterInput = document.createElement('input');
    letterInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    letterInput.id = 'letterInput';
    target.appendChild(letterInput);

    letterInput.addEventListener("focus", show);

// Create slider and its output
function addSlider() {

    // Slider + output container
    var letterSpan = document.createElement("span");
        letterSpan.id = "letterSpan";
        letterSpan.className = "mt-3";
        letterSpan.style.display = "block";
        target.appendChild(letterSpan);

    // Letter output
    var outputSlider = document.createElement("input");
       outputSlider.setAttribute('type', 'text');
       outputSlider.id = "outputSlider";
       outputSlider.style.border = "0";
        outputSlider.style.width = "25px";
       outputSlider.innerHTML = outputSlider.value;
       letterSpan.appendChild(outputSlider);

    // Slider
    var sliderContainer = document.createElement("span");
       sliderContainer.id = "sliderContainer";
       sliderContainer.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
       sliderContainer.style.height = "10px";
       sliderContainer.style.width = "300px";
       letterSpan.appendChild(sliderContainer);

    var sliderLetter = document.createElement('input');
       sliderLetter.setAttribute('type', 'range');
       sliderLetter.className = 'range-slider-handle';
       sliderLetter.id = 'sliderLetter';
       sliderLetter.min = 0;
       sliderLetter.max = 25;
       sliderLetter.value = 0;
       sliderLetter.style.width = "300px";
       sliderLetter.style.height = "5px";
       sliderLetter.innerHTML = sliderLetter.value;
       sliderContainer.appendChild(sliderLetter);
       sliderContainer.addEventListener("change", updateValue);

    // Update letter when using the slider
    function updateValue(event) {
        outputSlider.value = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(sliderLetter.value) + 65);
        letterInput.value = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(sliderLetter.value) + 65);
    }
}

// Button
var addLetter = document.createElement('button');
    addLetter.id = 'addLetter';
    addLetter.className = 'btn btn-secondary mt-3';
    addLetter.style.display = 'block';
    addLetter.innerHTML = 'Add letter';
    addLetter.style.display = "block";
    target.appendChild(addLetter);
    addLetter.addEventListener('click', addNewLetter);

// Show slider when click in name field
function show(event) {
    addSlider();
}

// Add new letter
function addNewLetter() {
    addSlider();
}
```

Can anyone give me a clue of what to look for? I don't necessarily need the answer, just some hint about what's going wrong and how I can solve the problem.

2 requirements, though: I'm not allowed to touch the HTML and it has to be pure JavaScript.

EDIT: For info, it's an exercise. It know it's not the best way to add letters in an input field, it's just to learn Javascript. :-)

Comment: Please revise to show your HTML (I assume that `#target` exists initially, at least). Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/41n5rtvf/) you could fork with the full code.

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide the code here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @04FS, that's not the point of the exercise.

Comment: Put the html code as well

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the html. It's very basic, lol: <div id="target"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function **updateValue(event)**, change the second line to this:

```
letterInput.value += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(sliderLetter.value) + 65);
// added +=
```

Add each new letter to the input field rather than replace each letter in the input field.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, actually there's a tiny problem: every time I'm moving the cursor, it adds a letter. It should only be one letter per cursor. But that's progress. :-)